# How to Blur background behind the UI only unreal 5

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

I'm new to Unreal game engine,but have some idea about how things works. I recently working on an archviz project and want to add some UI blur effect behind the UI element only. Here are some reference video that I'm talking about. I can't upload screen shot because there are some server problem while uploading photos.

https://youtu.be/bOQAAE2Hfhs

Answer (score 0):

You should use the UMG Background Blur widget: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/using-the-background-blur-widget-in-unreal-engine/